# Notice: undefined offset:1 in webservice/dispatcher.php line 36 in prestashop webservice

Tags: php, api, flutter, prestashop

I am using prestashop webservice api for building an application on flutter. However, when I try to get data from api url, I received response with notice of PHP  as "Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /webservice/dispatcher.php on line 36" and the list of objects. That makes me unable to decode the object to json.

I go to that file and the error is inside this block: (line 35, 36, 37)

```php
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']) && preg_match('/Basic\s+(.*)$/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'], $matches)) {
        list($name, $password) = explode(':', base64_decode($matches[1]));
        $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] = strip_tags($name);
}
```

When I try to get the result in postman or browser, there is no notice displayed at all.

Could anyone help me how to get rid of this notice or any solution to decode the object?  Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add a `var_dump($matches)` before the `list($name, $password) ...` line and see if it give you anything sensible?

Comment: @KoalaYeung it returns an array:
   `array(2) {
 [0]=>
string(50) "Basic M1E0OVE1VDhHTkJGVjdNUFI3SEc5RlQ0RVA5MlE0WkI="
[1]=>
 string(44) "M1E0OVE1VDhHTkJGVjdNUFI3SEc5RlQ0RVA5MlE0WkI="`

Comment: `base64_decode("M1E0OVE1VDhHTkJGVjdNUFI3SEc5RlQ0RVA5MlE0WkI=")` returns `3Q49Q5T8GNBFV7MPR7HG9FT4EP92Q4ZB`. There is no color `:` for your `list($name, $password)` to destructure. That why you encountered the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP's [list](https://www.php.net/list) syntax takes the right side of the assignment operator `=`, destructure it, then assign the children to the variables in it.

A list statement like this:

```php
list($name, $password) = $some_array;
```

Expects `$some_array` to be a numerical array with at least 2 children in it. If there is only 1, PHP would complain you're missing the 2nd item (offset 1). In your case, the explode call would require a `:` colon in the result of your [base64_decode](https://www.php.net/base64_decode) result, which might not be the case.

To prevent this, you may modify it to not directly destructure the result of your [explode](https://www.php.net/explode) call. Like this:

```php
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']) && preg_match('/Basic\s+(.*)$/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'], $matches)) {
        $name_and_password = explode(':', base64_decode($matches[1]));
        $name = $name_and_password[0] ?? ''; // if not set, default to be empty string ''
        $password = $name_and_password[1] ?? ''; // if not set, default to be empty string ''
        $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] = strip_tags($name);
}
```